# Laravel - How to enable exception handling in tests?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-7

I would like to handle the exception in tests via `App\Exceptions\Handler`.

I call `$this->withExceptionHandling();` in `handle()` method of the test, but no effect.

How can I do this?

> Laravel Framework 7.30.4

Comment: What do you mean you want to "enable handle exception" ?

Comment: @matiaslauriti When an exception is thrown somewhere else and not in tests, App\Exceptions\Handler is called. When an exception is thrown in tests App\Exceptions\Handler is not called.

Comment: You want to use `withoutExceptionHandling()`, that will throw the exception so you will be able to use `App\Exceptions\Handler`, but why do you want to do so ? Can you explain more, please ? There is something odd if you are trying to test something with `withoutExceptionHandling()`.

Comment: @matiaslauriti When I try to call `withoutExceptionHandling()`, nothing to happens. `App\Exceptions\Handler` is not called. I'm using dusk and want to send exceptions by email.